# PHP not transferring to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, stock

Okay so I am new to PHP and attempting to make a script that takes all of the data from a mysql database I have of stock prices and then looks to see if there was an increase in the stock price during after hours trading (by comparing one day's close price with the next day's open price). I have set up a few scripts like this that work, but for some reason this script isn't copying the data into my sql database and I am completely stumped as to why it won't.When I set up echo statements throughout I discovered that my code is seemingly being executed everywhere but the data isn't transferring. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
include("../includes/connect.php");

function masterLoop(){
$mainTickerFile = fopen("../tickerMaster.txt","r");
while (!feof($mainTickerFile)){
    $companyTicker = fgets($mainTickerFile);
    $companyTicker = trim($companyTicker);

    $nextDayIncrease = 0;
    $nextDayDecrease = 0;
    $nextDayNoChange = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $overnight_change = 0;
    $overnight_change_pct = 0;

    $sumOfIncreases = 0;
    $sumOfDecreases = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT date, open, close, percent_change FROM $companyTicker";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    if($result){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $date = $row['date'];
            $percent_change = $row['percent_change'];
            $open = $row['open'];
            $close = $row['close'];
            $sql2 = "SELECT date, open, close, percent_change FROM $companyTicker WHERE date > '$date' ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1";
            $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
            $numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result2);


            if($numberOfRows==1){
                $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
                $tom_date= $row2[0];
                $tom_open= $row2[1];
                $tom_close= $row2[2];
                $tom_percent_change= $row2[3];
                if ($close == 0){
                    $close = $tom_open;
                    }
                $overnight_change = $tom_open - $close;
                $overnight_change_pct = ($overnight_change/$close)*100;


                if($overnight_change_pct > 0){
                    $nextDayIncrease++;
                    $sumOfIncreases += $tom_percent_change;
                    $total++;

                }else if($overnight_change_pct < 0){
                    $nextDayDecrease++;
                    $sumOfDecreases += $tom_percent_change;
                    $total++;
                }else{
                    $nextDayNoChange++;
                    $total++;
                }

            }else if ($numberOfRows==0){
                $total = 1;
                $nextDayIncrease = 1;
                $nextDayDecrease = 1;
            }else{
                echo "You have an error in analysis_c3";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "unable to select $companyTicker <br />";
    }
    $nextDayIncreasePercent = ($nextDayIncrease/$total) * 100;
    $nextDayDecreasePercent = ($nextDayDecrease/$total) * 100;
    $averageIncreasePercentage = $sumOfIncreases/$nextDayIncrease;
    $averageDecreasePercentage = $sumOfDecreases/$nextDayDecrease;
    insertIntoResultTable($companyTicker, $nextDayIncrease, $nextDayIncreasePercent, $averageIncreasePercentage, $nextDayDecrease, $nextDayDecreasePercent, $averageDecreasePercentage);
}
}


function insertIntoResultTable($companyTicker, $nextDayIncrease, $nextDayIncreasePercent,     $averageIncreasePercentage, $nextDayDecrease, $nextDayDecreasePercent, $averageDecreasePercentage){

$buyValue = $nextDayIncreasePercent * $averageIncreasePercentage;
$sellValue = $nextDayDecreasePercent * $averageDecreasePercentage;
    $trueValue = $buyValue + $sellValue;

$query="SELECT * FROM analysisOvernightGain5 WHERE ticker='$companyTicker' ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($numberOfRows==1){
    $sql = "UPDATE analysisOvernightGain5 SET ticker='$companyTicker',daysInc='$nextDayIncrease',pctOfDaysInc='$nextDayIncreasePercent',avgIncPct='$averageIncreasePercentage',daysDec='$nextDayDecrease',pctOfDaysDec='$nextDayDecreasePercent',avgDecPct='$averageDecreasePercentage',buyValue='$buyValue',sellValue='$sellValue'trueValue='$trueValue' WHERE ticker='$companyTicker' ";
    mysql_query($sql);
}else{
    $sql="INSERT INTO analysisOvernightGain5 (ticker,daysInc,pctOfDaysInc,avgIncPct,daysDec,pctOfDaysDec,avgDecPct,buyValue,sellValue,trueValue) VALUES ('$companyTicker', '$nextDayIncrease', '$nextDayIncreasePercent', '$averageIncreasePercentage', '$nextDayDecrease', '$nextDayDecreasePercent', '$averageDecreasePercentage', '$buyValue', '$sellValue','$trueValue')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
}

masterLoop();
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at `mysql_error` for the `INSERT`/`UPDATE`?

Comment: Change all the `mysql_query($sql)` statements to `mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error())` to see if you're getting an error.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting but I don't really know what to make of it. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'trueValue='1.92496358566' WHERE ticker='A'' at line 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed `,` at `,sellValue='$sellValue'trueValue='$trueValue'`
it should be `,sellValue='$sellValue',trueValue='$trueValue'`

Comment: Thanks that seemed to do the trick! I am a little confused though because I copy and pasted that script as a template from another one I have and it is also missing that comma but that script still works.

Comment: It is strange to me...perhaps script does not reach to specific statement for showing the syntax error. i am not sure but maybe mysql statement syntax error in PHP, finding on run time